Applying Log Link to Quantile Regression
I was investigating quantile regression, and I got to thinking about how I would implement a log link (as I am using positive-bounded data). I've heard that quantile regression is equivariant under transformation, so I got to thinking, even though it's not the case in linear regression, does log-ing the response variable give the same effect as a log link? Does this work or am I applying the wrong ideas? I've noticed that there doesn't seem to be an easy way to specify a log-link in the "rq" function in R, so I'm trying to find a workaround.


I've heard that quantile regression is equivariant under transformation,

It isn't; quantiles are equivariant under monotonic-increasing transformation but linear relationships aren't.
For example, see the Wikipedia article:

In quantile regression for the $τ$th quantile we make the assumption that the $τ$th conditional quantile is given as a linear function of the explanatory variables

If your quantile functions are linear in predictors, transformation leaves you with nonlinear functions.
If you were estimating quantiles separately at each combination of predictors, it would be transformation equivariant, but quantile regression doesn't normally do that; typically you relate the quantiles across different values of the x's.
A smooth additive version of quantile regression would sort of work but the smoothing would be impacted (e.g. a typical kernel regression  would not yield the same observation weights either side of a non-linear transformation). So it wouldn't quite be invariant to transformation.

I got to thinking about how I would implement a log link (as I am using positive-bounded data).

If you had a quantile version of a GLM, or some form of nonlinear-quantile regression, perhaps you can implement a log-link, but I'm not sure I've seen any offhand.

Does this work or am I applying the wrong ideas? I've noticed that there doesn't seem to be an easy way to specify a log-link in the "rq" function in R, so I'm trying to find a workaround.

I assume you mean the one in quantreg. As far as I recall, quantreg::rq works with linear relationships.
However, I believe the same package has a local-polynomial regression function.
Within rq I don't know of any implementation of link functions in the sense of there being a transformed-linear predictor fitted to some quantile.
This sort of thing could in principle be done, so I expect it probably has been, but I don't think it's in rq
However, because of the equivariance of order under monotonic transformation, if did have such an ability to fit a link function, I believe that should give the same fit as transforming the data (where that is possible*) by the link function (or indeed any linear function of the inverse of the mean-function), fitting the linear quantile regression and then transforming the result back.
That should work in rq.
Indeed, like so:
library(quantreg)
x=runif(300,3,12) # generate some data
y=rgamma(300,2,scale=exp(-1+0.24*x)) # log link

qmdl=rq(log(y)~x,tau=0.9)
qfit=exp(fitted(qmdl))
o=order(x)
oo=order(order(o))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x,log(y))
abline(qmdl,col=4,lty=2,lwd=2)
plot(x,y)
lines(x[oo],qfit[oo],col=4,lty=2,lwd=2)



* It isn't always possible to do this. For example consider a  Gaussian GLM with a log-link where the mean is small  somewhere (relative to the standard deviation of the error term) you may have negative data values. Then there would be no correspondence between transforming a quantile's link function to linearity and the quantile of the transformed data. Then you couldn't use that linearizing approach to get a shortcut in general. However, even there, a modified version could be made to work, at least in some cases. It would still be a problem if the quantile of interest itself didn't keep to within the support where it could be transformed. You would see similar issues with a Poisson GLM (where you could see zeroes) or a binomial GLM (zeroes or ones), at least with some link functions.

@Daniel I finally realized what you were probably getting at; quantile regression (per wikipedia, and numerous papers) being linear as a result, I didn't fully put together the idea that you could have been asking about equivalence of a GLM-like version of quantile regression vs transforming the data by the link function to make that link function linear so you could use a standard quantile regression function like  rq. I have added a couple of paragraphs at the end. I believe that should work, sorry to be dense.
